# c++20 concept limited by member access specifier

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm currently testing the visual studio implementation of c++20 concepts.

The following concept works fine:

```
template <typename Cmd, typename T>
concept HasApplyState = requires (Cmd c, T x) { {c.apply_state(x)}->bool; };
```

as long as *apply_state()* method is public.

But, is there a way to grant access to protected members in ***requires*** expressions ?

Imagine a case of a template class declaration with a policy template parameter intended to be a base class:

```
template <typename T, typename Policy, bool = HasApplyState<Policy, T> >
class MyClass : protected Policy
{
    ...
};
template <typename T, typename Policy>
class MyClass<T, Policy, false> : protected Policy, protected DefaultApplyStateInterface<T>
{
    ...
};
```

I would like to know if *MyClass* will have access to *apply_state()* that may be protected.

Is that a limitation of the c++20 concepts design ?